# GeoDjango, difference between dwithin and distance_lt?

Tags: django, geospatial, geodjango

Using geoDjango, what is the difference between

```
myObj.objects.filter(point__dwithin(...etc.))
```

and

```
myObj.objects.filter(point__distance_lt(...etc.))
```

?
Are they the same thing, or are they doing subtly different things?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I did some research but I don't know if the results are of any use ;)

- I looked at the [unit tests](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/gis/tests/distapp/tests.py) that they use to test the DB queries but they don't give real hints (to me).
- I tried to compare the generated SQL:

I have already a geo application using a **PostgreSQL** databse. When I perform this query with **`__distance_lt`**:

```
Place.objects.filter(location__distance_lt=(p.location, D(km=1))).query.as_sql()
```

I get this generated SQL:

```
SELECT (some_fields_here)
FROM "places_place" 
WHERE ST_distance_sphere("places_place"."location", %s) < 1000.0
```

When I try to use do to the same with **`__dwithin`**, I get an error:

```
Place.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(p.location, D(km=1))).query.as_sql()

TypeError: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries.
```

So I had to change the query to no use a **`D`** object:

```
Place.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(p.location, 1)).query.as_sql()
```

which results in

```
SELECT (some fields here) 
FROM "places_place" 
WHERE ST_DWithin("places_place"."location", %s, 1)
```

---

**Summary:**

**`__dwithin`**
 - takes degree values as distance parameter.
 - uses `ST_DWithin` SQL function.

**`__distance_lt`**
 - can take other distance values ;).
 - uses `ST_distance_sphere` SQL function.

Btw, I get different results with both queries but I guess this is mostly due the fact that I don't know which "degree" value to use.

Comment: hi! :) this is an extremely useful answer

Comment: Note **dwithin** is fastest since it makes best use of the spatial index [see discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845133/how-can-i-query-all-my-data-within-a-distance-of-5-meters).

Comment: @FelixKling the dwithin value is in **metres**, per the [postgis docs](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

Comment: @s29: After looking at the documentation today (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin) it indeed looks like `dwithin` accepts distance objects now. Maybe the error message given was incorrect. I can only assume that this changed over the years. I will update my answer. Thanks!