# How can I query all my data within a distance of 5 meters?

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I am using GeoDjango with PostGIS. Then I am into trouble on how to query my postgres db table to get all data within a distance of 5 meters.

**UPDATES1**
I am using GeoDjango 1.2.7

I found something from this url https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-distance_lte

Zipcode.objects.filter(**poly__distance_lte**=(**geom**, **D**(**m**=5)))

But don't know on how to prepare the parameter and variables.

1. what is **poly_distance_lte**? is a function?
2. what is **geom**? is a variable? how to create it?
3. what is **D**? is a function? if yes, **m** is a parameter name of **D** function?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.

Answer (score 10):

In general, the best PostGIS function for such a query is **[ST_DWithin()](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_DWithin.html)**:

> Returns true if the geometries are within the specified distance of one another.

eg. all customers that live within 1000 meters of shop #1:

```
SELECT customers.* 
FROM customers, shops
WHERE ST_DWithin(customers.the_geog, shops.the_geog, 1000)
  AND shop.id = 1
```

ST_DWithin will use the **spatial index** which you should have created and therefore outperform ST_Distance.

In Django there seems to be a corresponding filter called **[dwithin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-distance_lte)**:

> Returns models where the distance to the geometry field from the lookup geometry are within the given distance from one another.
>
> ```
> Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__dwithin=(geom, D(m=5)))
> Backend   SQL Equivalent
> PostGIS   ST_DWithin(poly, geom, 5)
> ```

D(m=5) returns a distance object of length 5 meters

geom is the geometry from which you want to calculate distances to Zipcode objects

dwithin() is the function used

poly is the geometry attribute of Zipcode objects

```
z = Zipcode(code=77096, poly='POLYGON(( 10 10, 10 20, 20 20, 20 15, 10 10))')
```

Comment: Like what I've posted earlier, what is `D` and `geom` there? `m` is parameter name of `D` isn't? `poly` is the point? `__dwithin` is a function isn't?

Comment: I tried it but can't recognize. D is compile error. how about `poly`, what is it?

Comment: I appreciate your responses. How about spatial index creation? would you mean that I need to do some task to create it? If yes, How could be?

Comment: any sample on how to do spatial indexing

Comment: +1 for explaining distance vs within and which is faster (because the syntax and usage in django docs for distance_lte and dwithin is identical and it doesn't give any hint what to use)

Answer (score 1):

I just did this a few days ago.

it is fairly hard because you should create a geography rather than a geometry point, to have access to meter unit.

so I just did it in a small extra where query

```
extra_where = '''
    ST_Intersects(
            the_geom, geometry(ST_Buffer(ST_GeographyFromText(\'%s\'), %f)))
'''
your_point = 'POINT(1 2)'
your_distance = 5 # meters
YourModule.object.filter(something).extra(where=extra_where%(your_point, your_distance))
```

notice the geography part and the buffer part.

Comment: I have two (2) clarifications.. 1) Why didn't you use the ST_Distance(..) < 5? I am thinking of using ST_Distance (e.g. Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__distance_lte=(geom, D(m=5)))) but don't know on how to prepare the parameter. 2) I kinda newbie with Python GeoDjango, would you give an example on how to use that and please include on how to prepare the parameter values.

Comment: @eros 1 ST_Distance tests a lot of geometries (maybe all geometrys in the entire table if you don't filter), buffer and intersect performs better as far as I tried. 2 I myself am newbie, too, I will update the answer soon

Comment: how about the 'the_geom' and 'geometry' there? - thanks a lot. I look forward to see your updated answer. Also, thanks for considering the performance. I missed that points. Regards.

Comment: oh, I have already updated it. geometry is, a geometry field in django and in postgis, where you store your map/location/... what ever geo data, the default geometry for a table is 'the_geom'. replace it with your own geometry field name.

Comment: You should use ST_DWithin instead of the buffer+intersects solution. ST_DWithin will use the spatial index which you should have created and therefore outperform ST_Distance. Creating buffer geometries is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @underdark would you post it as answer. and please include a snippet.

Comment: @tdihp 'the_geom' is field name in my table1. But I can't understand the 'geometry' part. geometry is also a field name of my table1?

Comment: @underdark ST_DWithin as far as I remember will use original length measurment, not meter. and, as far as I tried, django Distance class doesn't solve this.

Comment: @tdihp ST_DWithin will use original length measurements if geometries are used and meters if geographies are used.

Answer (score 1):

1. what is poly__distance_lte? is a function?

The document page assumes `poly` to be the name of the geometry field within your `Zipcode` model. `distance_lte` is just a lookup filter that finds objects within a certain distance of a point.

---

1. what is geom? is a variable? how to create it?

It's a previously defined variable. To find `Zipcode` objects with the `poly` field that are within a distance of x miles from point A, you need to define point A. `geom` is that definition. For example, it could be a `django.contrib.gis.geos.Point`. You can set the latitude and longitude of that point and use it as the center of your search circle. In the example you obtained, this center is named `geom`

---

1. what is D? is a function? if yes, m is a parameter name of D function?

`D` is a class. More specifically, it's a short alias for the class called `Distance`. They both can be found in `django.contrib.gis.measure`. You can create an instance of this class using various real world distance metrics such as kilometers, miles, meter. In this case m is for meter.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance, D

d1 = Distance(km=5)
print d1
d2 = D(mi=5) # `D` is an alias for `Distance`
print d2
5.0 mi
```

[reference from django project](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/12930/gis_docs.1.diff)